# Angular 6 routing to root from aux routes

Tags: angular, routes

I have a main navbar at the top with items Home(`/`) and Information(`/information`). On `/information`, I also have a sidebar with a bunch of items. I'm using aux routing for these items so that I'm getting something like `/information(aux:item1)`.

Whenever I route to any of my main navbar's routes I get a `Cannot match any routes` error with an extra slash in front of my URLs. So if I click on Home, I expect the URL to be `/`, but it's `//` instead.

Here's some code:

> app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: full },
    { 
        path: 'information',
        component: InformationComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'item1', component: OneComponent, outlet: 'aux' },
            { path: 'item1', component: TwoComponent, outlet: 'aux' },
            ...
        ]
    }
];
```

> navbar.component.ts

```
routes = [
    { name: 'Home',  path: '/' },
    { name: 'Information', path: '/information' },
    ...
];

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart)
            console.log(event.url); // Prints '//' when navigated to '/' and '//information' when navigated to '/information'
    }
}
```

> navbar.component.html

```
<a *ngFor="let r of routes" '[routerLink]'="[{ outlets: { primary: route.path, aux: null } }]">{{ route.name }}</a>
```

> information.component.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'aux': 'item1' } }]"></a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'aux': 'item2' } }]"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I guess my question is, why is an extra slash being added to my routes? And how do I fix this so I can go back and forth between aux routes and primary root routes?

Answer (score 0):

Remove / from the routes.path it will work for reference see

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/aux-routes.html

Comment: I don't have any leading slashes in routes.path

Comment: routes = [ { name: 'Home', path: '/' }, { name: 'Information', path: '/information' }, ... ]; For this one

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. But when I remove the leading slash, it routes to something like `/information/(information//aux:item1)`. It appends the route to the aux route instead of root.